# Keeping track of users history in express to make a 'back' button?

Tags: node.js, express, back, multiple-users

I'm making an express app and I want to include a 'back' button in the app UI that does basically exactly what the browser back button does.

I tried holding an array variable in the server that simply collects all of the URL params visited. For example, for the `'/:lang'` route ...

```
const browsingHistory = [];

app.get("/:lang", (req, res) => {
  const lang = req.params.lang;
  if (lang === "en" || lang === "fr") {
    const templateVars = {
      menuItems: db[lang].menuItems,
      lang,
    };
    res.render("root", templateVars);
  }
  if (lang !== "favicon.ico") {
    browsingHistory.push(lang);
    console.log(`Browsing history: ${browsingHistory}`);
  }
});
```

BUT I'm realizing this only works when locally hosted — once deployed, if there are multiple users simultaneously, how to keep track of each users' individual history? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'm slightly confused: express is your _server_, it has no UI itself. What _client_ is connecting to your server? Because that is the thing that should maintain a navigation history (since that's what's doing the navigating). Not express.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the browsing history will require user sessions. On each request, you will have to store the route that the user hits in their session variable.

In Express, this can be accomplished with the [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) library. You will want to initiate each session with some `history` property that begins as an empty array. Once express-session is set up, you can do something similar to the following

```js
app.get("/:lang", (req, res) => {
  const lang = req.params.lang;
  req.session.history.push(lang);

  ...
});

app.get("/getMyPageHistory", (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.session.history);
});
```

`req.session` will be unique for each user. So, you can store each user's unique history in this variable.

With that said, if you go down this route, you eventually will want some external session storage. By default, sessions are saved in your server's memory. This introduces a few issues that are explained in the express-session documentation. Here is their warning

> Warning The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process, and is meant for debugging and developing.

They provide a [list of compatible session stores](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores)